# Como se diz «hover» em português?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Em informática, existe o conceito de *hover* para quando se passa o ponteiro do rato por cima de qualquer coisa.
Mais do que passar por cima, é pairar por cima: quando o rato fica parado por cima de algo, está *hovering*.

- Como se diz isto em português?

Frases exemplo:

> - O botão fica azul quando fazes *hover* nele.
> - Devia aparecer uma dica com a hora exata, quando o utilizador faz *hover* no texto «há N horas atrás».

---

Definição de hover no dicionário [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hover):

> Definition of hover
>    (...)
>
> transitive verb
>   : to position (a computer cursor) over something (such as an image or icon) without selecting it
>
> > Many in the class hovered their cursors over words and icons for long periods before committing to clicking their mouse. —Kelly Heyboer
>
> intransitive verb
>   1
>   a : to hang fluttering in the air or on the wing
>
> > A hawk hovered overhead.
>
> b : to remain suspended over a place or object
>
> > a hummingbird hovering over the flowers
> >     Helicopters hovered above us.
>
> 2
>   a : to move to and fro near a place : fluctuate around a given point
>
> > Unemployment hovered around 10 percent.
>
> b : to be in a state of uncertainty, irresolution, or suspense
>
> > … hovering uncomfortably behind a cigar … —Tennessee Williams
> >     The country hovers on the brink of famine.

Comment: Sempre escutei e disse "passar por cima".

Comment: Acredito que a melhor tradução seria "pairar", talvez em algum cenário "flutuar" fique bom, outra opção é usar "... passar/ficar/estar sobre o botão"

Comment: Também podes dizer *peneirar* [(Aulete 6)](http://www.aulete.com.br/peneirar) ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Teu comentário é uma resposta. Adiciono a possibilidade "posicionar" o ponteiro sobre algo.

Comment: @stafusa valeu pela dica, resposta postada, ainda to começando na comunidade, não sei bem como funciona

Comment: Está ótimo, @GuilhermeCostamilam. Os comentários, além da função padrão de pedir esclarecimentos, podem mesmo ser usados para sugerir respostas menos embasadas ou incompletas. É uma questão de julgamento se a resposta é boa o bastante para ser postada ou fica mesmo melhor como mero comentário. De início, para aprender, sugiro que, na dúvida, poste a resposta: a comunidade então poderá lhe dar um feedback por meio das possíveis edições da resposta, dos votos para cima e/ou para baixo e dos comentários.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Mas você já é um usuário experiente no SO em português, desculpe se ensino o padre a rezar. :-)

Comment: @stafusa acho que sou inexperiente no SO-pt, apenas sou ativo, pergunto e respondo com certa frequência, valeu pela ajuda, agora, na dúvida, vou arriscar

Answer (score 4):

No Google tradutor, as opções são:

- flutuar
- pairar
- ficar suspenso no ar
- voar lentamente
- girar em volta de
- rondar em torno de

Acredito que a melhor tradução seria "pairar", talvez em algum cenário "flutuar" fique bom.

Outra opção, mais usada e, provavelmente, melhor, é "passar/ficar/estar sobre/por cima"

Como sugerido pelo @stafusa, "posicionar" também é uma possibilidade

Nas frases de exemplo da pergunta, com as modificações necessárias:

- O botão fica azul quando fazes hover nele:

  - O botão fica azul ao pairar o ponteiro nele.
  - O botão fica azul ao passar o ponteiro por cima dele.
  - O botão fica azul ao posicionar o ponteiro sobre ele.
- Devia aparecer uma dica com a hora exata, quando o utilizador faz hover no texto «há N horas atrás»:

  - Devia aparecer uma dica com a hora exata, quando o utilizador paira o ponteiro em cima do texto «há N horas atrás».
  - Devia aparecer uma dica com a hora exata, quando o utilizador ficar com o ponteiro em cima do texto «há N horas atrás».
  - Devia aparecer uma dica com a hora exata, quando o ponteiro do utilizador está sobre o texto «há N horas atrás».

Mas se eu estou falando com alguém da área (que sabe o que é o evento de hover), nem tento traduzir, o uso como um neologismo

Apesar de haver uma diferença entre os eventos de foco e *hover*, não vejo problema em usar o primeiro para se referir ao segundo ou a ambos, já que costumam ser usados juntos. Não vejo problema se usado para explicar para uma pessoa leiga, usar um para se referir ao outro, falando com alguém que sabe diferencia-los (um web designer, por exemplo), pode causar confusões

Comment: É, "se pairares o cursor sobre o botão ele fica azul"; mas estamos a inovar . Até agora nós não pairávamos uma coisa; a coisa é que pairava; ou seja o verbo *pairar* era só intransitivo. Se quiséssemos respeitar a tradição, teríamos de dizer "se fizeres pairar o cursor..."

Comment: «Outra opção, mais usada e, provavelmente, melhor, é "passar/ficar/estar sobre/por cima». Neste contexto especifico acho que é o que mais se adequa para traduzir "hover".

Comment: @Jacinto imagino um uso do tipo, "ao pairar o cursor ...", usando no infinitivo, em vez de conjugar, só não sei se seria correto de acordo com a norma culta da língua

Comment: @Jacinto na verdade, também parece ter sido isso que aconteceu com o inglês - o verbo era intransitivo, e no contexto informático tornou-se transitivo. Gosto mais e mais dessa opção, do «pairar» transitivo.

Comment: Guilherme, não queres incluir na tua resposta propostas de tradução das frases exemplo?

Comment: @Guilherme, é perfeitamente gramatical, mas pode não se ajustar a alguns contextos. Por exemplo, "Many in the class hovered their cursors over words and icons for long periods before committing to clicking their mouse" [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hover). Aqui a construção "ao pairar" não serve; terias de dizer, "muitos posicionaram/fizeram pairar..."; ou inovas e dizes, "muitos pairaram o cursor..." Nos exemplos da pergunta (é boa a sugestão do ANeves de incluíres as frases exemplos; só assim se vê se uma construção funciona bem), terias de eliminar >>

Comment: >> a referência ao utilizador para poderes usar o "ao pairar".

Comment: @ANeves, creio que tens razão, no [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hover), o único uso transitivo indicado para *hover* é o informático; todos os outros usos são intransitivos. Também não me choca nada transitivar o *pairar*, para agilizar a língua. Mas tens que atender à situação; podes não querer usar uma construção não consagrada num documento formal, por exemplo. De qualquer modo, é melhor que "fazer hover".

Comment: @ANeves adicionei possíveis traduções para cada frase de exemplo da pergunta, também adicionei mais uma possibilidade no final

Comment: @ANeves a mim soa-me mal "ao pairar o ponteiro".

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, a mim também... porque achas que fiz esta pergunta? ;)